# How to remove sub string or specific set of characters from a string using Jquery or JS.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string as shown below

`ABCD+QRTE+ASDF+XYZ`

Now i want to remove **QRTE** sub string or those characters from the string and return the remaining string as shown below

`ABCD+ASDF+XYZ`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to remove `+QRTE` or `QRTE+`, not just `QRTE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var str = 'ABCD+QRTE+ASDF+XYZ';
var newStr = str.replace('+QRTE', '');

alert(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should remove the target string no matter where it is in the sequence

```
var str = 'ABCD+QRTE+ASDF+XYZ';
var newStr = str.split('+').filter(function(item) { return item != 'QRTE'; }).join('+');
```